# Finding center of image for rotation in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

So I have this piece of code, which pretty much draws various 2D textures on the screen, though there are multiple sprites that have to be 'dissected' from the texture (spritesheet). The problem is that rotation is not working properly; while it rotates, it does not rotate on the center of the texture, which is what I am trying to do. I have narrowed it down to the translation being incorrect:

```
    glTranslatef(x + sr->x/2 - sr->w/2,
                 y + sr->y/2 - sr->h/2,0);

    glRotatef(ang,0,0,1.f);

    glTranslatef(-x + -sr->x/2 - -sr->w/2,
                 -y + -sr->y/2 - -sr->h/2,0);
```

X and Y is the position that it's being drawn to, the sheet rect struct contains the position X and Y of the sprite being drawn from the texture, along with w and h, which are the width and heights of the 'sprite' from the texture. I've tried various other formulas, such as:

```
 glTranslatef(x, y, 0);

 The below three switching the negative sign to positive (x - y to x + y)

 glTranslatef(sr->x/2 - sr->w/2, sr->y/2 - sr->h/2 0 );

 glTranslatef(sr->x - sr->w/2, sr->y - sr->h/2, 0 );

 glTranslatef(sr->x - sr->w, sr->y - sr->w, 0 );

 glTranslatef(.5,.5,0);
```

It might also be helpful to say that:

```
glOrtho(0,screen_width,screen_height,0,-2,10);
```

is in use.

I've tried reading various tutorials, going through various forums, asking various people, but there doesn't seem to be a solution that works, nor can I find any useful resources that explain to me how I find the center of the image in order to translate it to '(0,0)'. I'm pretty new to OpenGL so a lot of this stuff takes awhile for me to digest.

Here's the entire function:

```
void Apply_Surface( float x, float y, Sheet_Container* source, Sheet_Rect* sr , float ang = 0, bool flipx = 0, bool flipy = 0, int e_x = -1, int e_y = -1 ) {
 float imgwi,imghi;

 glLoadIdentity();
 glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,source->rt());     
 // rotation
 imghi = source->rh();
 imgwi = source->rw();
 Sheet_Rect t_shtrct(0,0,imgwi,imghi);
 if ( sr == NULL ) // in case a sheet rect is not provided, assume it's width
                   //and height of texture with 0/0 x/y
    sr = &t_shtrct;

 glPushMatrix();

     // 
     int wid, hei;
     glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH,&wid);
     glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT,&hei);
     glTranslatef(-sr->x + -sr->w,
                 -sr->y + -sr->h,0);
     glRotatef(ang,0,0,1.f);

     glTranslatef(sr->x + sr->w,
                 sr->y + sr->h,0);

     // Yeah, out-dated way of drawing to the screen but it works for now.
     GLfloat tex[] = {
        (sr->x+sr->w * flipx) /imgwi, 1 - (sr->y+sr->h  *!flipy )/imghi,
        (sr->x+sr->w * flipx) /imgwi, 1 - (sr->y+sr->h  * flipy)/imghi,
        (sr->x+sr->w * !flipx) /imgwi, 1 - (sr->y+sr->h * flipy)/imghi,
        (sr->x+sr->w * !flipx) /imgwi, 1 - (sr->y+sr->h *!flipy)/imghi
     };
     GLfloat vertices[] = { // vertices to put on screen
          x,        (y + sr->h),
          x,         y,
         (x +sr->w), y,
         (x +sr->w),(y +sr->h)
     };
     // index array
     GLubyte index[6] = { 0,1,2, 2,3,0 };
     float fx = (x/(float)screen_width)-(float)sr->w/2/(float)imgwi;
     float fy = (y/(float)screen_height)-(float)sr->h/2/(float)imghi;

     // activate arrays
     glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
     glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
     // pass verteices and texture information
     glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
     glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);
     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, index);

     glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
     glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

 glPopMatrix();

 glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}
```

Sheet container class:

```
class Sheet_Container {
    GLuint texture;
    int width, height;
public:
    Sheet_Container();
    Sheet_Container(GLuint, int = -1,int = -1);
    void Load(GLuint,int = -1,int = -1);
    float rw();
    float rh();
    GLuint rt();
};
```

Sheet rect class:

```
struct Sheet_Rect {
    float x, y, w, h;
    Sheet_Rect();
    Sheet_Rect(int xx,int yy,int ww,int hh);
};
```

Image loading function:

```
Sheet_Container Game_Info::Load_Image(const char* fil) {
    ILuint t_id;
    ilGenImages(1, &t_id);
    ilBindImage(t_id);
    ilLoadImage(const_cast<char*>(fil));
    int width = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH), height = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    return Sheet_Container(ilutGLLoadImage(const_cast<char*>(fil)),width,height);
}
```

Comment: Your description concerns me: "it does not rotate on the center of the texture" is rather vague. I assume you are drawing a texture-mapped quad and what you are trying to rotate is that quad? The version of GL you are using still supports texture matrices, so it is equally possible that you are referring to rotation and translation of texture coordinates by themselves (though this would produce some weird results when using a sprite sheet).

Comment: Yeah, I'm loading an image using the devIL library's ilLoadImage function. I believe it's a quad. Basically, the draw function binds the GL_TEXTURE_2D texture, pushes a new matrix, does this rotation stuff, and then draws to the screen. I can post the entire function if necessary. But, anyways, I'm trying to rotate it around the "center" of the sprite/image itself. Currently it's rotating at the upper-left of the image if I don't translate it.

Comment: Okay, so you want to rotate this quad around its center. I think you are going to have to post more code, I cannot figure out the dimensions of your quad from what you have shown.

Comment: I posted more code; dimensions of the quad change from texture to texture as multiple are being displayed.

Comment: In the "entire function," you have a rotation of 0 degrees. Was that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The 0 should be replaced with "ang"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your quad (two triangles) is centered at:

```
( x + sr->w / 2,  y + sr->h / 2 )
```

#### You need to move that point to the origin, rotate, and then move it back:

```
 glTranslatef ( (x + sr->w / 2.0f),  (y + sr->h / 2.0f), 0.0f); // 3rd
 glRotatef    (0,0,0,1.f);                                      // 2nd
 glTranslatef (-(x + sr->w / 2.0f), -(y + sr->h / 2.0f), 0.0f); // 1st
```

Here is where I think you are getting tripped up. People naturally assume that OpenGL applies transformations in the order they appear (top-to-bottom), that is not the case. OpenGL effectively swaps the operands everytime it multiplies two matrices:

```
M1 x M2 x M3
~~~~~~~
  (1)
  ~~~~~~~~~~
      (2)

(1) M2 * M1
(2) M3 * (M2 * M1)   -->   M3 * M2 * M1  (row-major / textbook math notation)
```

The technical term for this is post-multiplication, it all has to do with the way matrices are implemented in OpenGL (column-major). Suffice it to say, you should generally read `glTranslatef`, `glRotatef`, `glScalef`, etc. calls from bottom-to-top.

#### With that out of the way, your current rotation does not make any sense.

You are telling GL to rotate **0 degrees** around an axis: **<0,0,1>** (the z-axis in other words). The axis is correct, but a **0 degree** rotation is not going to do anything ;)

Comment: Yeah, the 0 degree rotation was accidental, I only put it there in order to not rotate as I test some other things out. Didn't notice that I copy/pasted it in there. And yeah, the post multiplication thing I am aware of. But the code you posted worked, thank you a lot! The trouble I was having was how to find the center, but I have a better grasp of how to do it now.